# How do I build a good defense for character in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a Reguard *Warrior* in Skyrim, but in just about every battle I get my backside handed to me. In fact my follower is stronger and can take hits better than I can, and I don't think she even equipped the shoes or vest I gave her.

For instance, last night I get my bum handed to me by a Frost Troll, Regular Troll, and a Dragon for a total of 20+ plus times. Kind of makes the game un-enjoyable.

I've only been able to get to level 9, due to the fact that I can't stand in a fight for 1 minute without dying. The only good things is that I find some really great stuff to sell, but no thanks to my character, thank my follower. Now I can buy some property in Whiterun.

So what skills should I pump points into for a Redgaurd (I have like 5 that I have not used)?
Where can I get good weapons and armor for my level?
What other skills and tips can I use to stay alive?

Comment: What kind of character are you going for? Mage? warrior? ranger? thief? a hybrid? Each playstyle usually has a boon for being defensive. Mage's for example, Can dual cast destruction spells to stun opponents and throw up powerful armor spells and wards - as well as conjure powerful allies.

Comment: @Resorath That's a good point. Giving more details one the type of character b01 is going for could help users give you more relevant answers.

Comment: Play on an easier difficulty level.

Comment: I'm a warrior type.

Comment: I'm too proud of a player to play at an easier setting. Besides, I'm sure I just need to tweak how I'm building my character and I'll do better. Otherwise, very funny :)

Comment: Why would someone even fight a dragon on level lower than nine? Skyrim's main quest is *not* supposed to be done all at once. On low levels you're weak so do quests that won't get you killed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way to stop your character getting dominated in big fights is to pump up your health each level increase.

On my last character, I was playing an archer whom I assumed would rarely get into a close-combat situation that I couldn't just kite out of. I spent each level increase on stamina so I could run further (as part of the hit-and-run tactic I was trying). It was great, except for every so often when I'd come up against something that pinned me down or shot at me from a distance. I was about to restart, but instead started investing in more health. All of a sudden, the game started to get easier. That character got to level 51 with over 300 health.

Other tips would be:

- Invest in skills that increase your base damage for your weapon type. For example, maxing out the base skill for one-handed doubles your damage every single hit.
- If you're looking for superior equipment, invest some skills in Smithing. If you go along the RIGHT hand side of the skill tree, you can craft the strongest weapons/armour for a light or heavy fighter or archer and improve them to legendary quality.
- For fights against dragons and powerful enemies, keep some potions of fortify archery/one-handed/two-handed/destruction or whatever you're using to increase your damage. The sooner they die, the less damage they can do.
- Carry potions of restore health attached to a hotkey so you can quickly restore health if you need to (if on the PC version, "favourite" them in the items menu, then press Q when out of the menu to open your favourites list. Move the selection over the item and press 1-8 to attach it to that hotkey).
- Carry potions of resist frost/fire/shock/magic. A resistance of 40% almost halves the damage an enemy relying on that type of damage can do.
- You can save money if you make these potions yourself. Consider investing some points in Alchemy (just the base skill, physician and benefactor is enough. Print an alchemy effects guide to find out what ingredients do, or just eat one of each ingredient to find an effect, then discover the rest through trial and error). Restore health, for instance, can be made quite simply with Blisterwort or Blue Mountain Flowers and Wheat.
- If you rely on melee weapons, consider carrying a reasonable bow and some arrows (the arrows are weightless, the bow is fairly light too). In some situations, jumping on top of some rubble and shooting that warhammer-wielding master vampire is the smartest choice.
- Let your companion attract the attention of nearby enemies and take the hits. They sound like a jerk for letting you die so often anyway. Target an enemy that is attacking your companion, so that you get a few hits in before they even realise they're being attacked by someone else.

If you let us know what character type you're playing, we can give more specific advice. Hope this helps for now.

Comment: Small comment about Smithing that everyone seems to forget. Plate Armor which is heavy, is only accessible on the left side of the tree after Elven armor. Don't know why they did that, but they did :)

Comment: @GmNoob That is a bit strange, isn't it? I recommended the right hand side of the skill tree because it leads to both Daedric and Dragon equipment, which is all you really need end-game. The left hand-side ends with Dragon, even though it looks like it will loop around to Daedric :)

Comment: On the point of Plate armor: it's not worth the perks wasted on the light armors to get there, compared to Orcish. Kinda a worthless value-add for the light armorers.